# separating output integers to two values

Tags: javascript, split, integer, output

```
var currentPageURL = "www.javascript.com/dun/1.70 80";
var url = getMeasurementsFromUrl(currentPageURL)

document.write(url);

function getMeasurementsFromUrl(url)
{

var urlMeasurmentString = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/dun/')+5);

urlMeasurmentString =urlMeasurmentString.replace("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz",""); 
urlMeasurmentString =urlMeasurmentString.replace(",","."); 
urlMeasurmentString =urlMeasurmentString.replace("/","."); 
urlMeasurmentString =urlMeasurmentString.replace("-",".");
urlMeasurmentString =urlMeasurmentString.replace(",","."); 
urlMeasurmentString =urlMeasurmentString.replace("/","."); 
urlMeasurmentString =urlMeasurmentString.replace("-",".");
return urlMeasurmentString;
}
```

​I need to split the output which is '1.70 80' to two individual integers.
http://jsfiddle.net/mqWGm/

Comment: An integer is a whole number `1.70` is a float. Should it be rounded (or up, down)..? Or left as a float?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var currentPageURL = "www.javascript.com/dun/1.70 80";
var url = getMeasurementsFromUrl(currentPageURL)
var integers = url.split(' ');
for(var i = 0; i<integers.length; i++)
{
    integers[i] = parseFloat(integers[i],2);
}
console.log(integers);

function getMeasurementsFromUrl(url)
{

var urlMeasurmentString = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/dun/')+5);

urlMeasurmentString =urlMeasurmentString.replace("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz","");
urlMeasurmentString =urlMeasurmentString.replace(",",".");
urlMeasurmentString =urlMeasurmentString.replace("/",".");
urlMeasurmentString =urlMeasurmentString.replace("-",".");
urlMeasurmentString =urlMeasurmentString.replace(",",".");
urlMeasurmentString =urlMeasurmentString.replace("/",".");
urlMeasurmentString =urlMeasurmentString.replace("-",".");
return urlMeasurmentString;
}
```

or better:

```
var currentPageURL = "www.javascript.com/dun/1.70 80";
console.log(getIntegers(currentPageURL));

function getIntegers(url){
    url = url.split('/');
    url = url[url.length-1].split(' ');
    for(var i = 0; i<url.length; i++)
    {
        url[i] = parseFloat(url[i],2);
    }
    return url;
}
```

Comment: "1.70 80".split(" ") will give "1.70" and "80" and parseInt will stumble on "1.70". Change the parseInt to parseFloat.

Answer (score 0):

If you want 1.70 and 80 then you can just do

```
urlMeasurementString.split(" ");
```

This will return an array where the first element is 1.70 and the second element is 80;

Comment: @user1792316 could you please accept this answer if it's what you were looking for

Answer (score 0):

1.70 is not an integer, but if you need to numbers from the string "1.70 80" you can do something like the following:

```
var atoms = url.split(" ");
var num1 = parseFloat(atoms[0]);
var num2 = parseFloat(atoms[1]);
```